# How to change default location of .sln file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, solution

I'd like my .sln to always live within my project folder. How can I make this the default behavior when creating a new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the "Create directory for solution" checkbox when you save the solution for the first time.  Visual Studio memorizes this choice, it will stay unchecked when you create and save new solutions, until you change it again.

Answer (score 3):

To change the creation location for a new website, you can change this registry key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\
    NewProjectDialog\MRUSettingsVenusProjectLocationEntries\Value0
```

As it is a Most Recently Used setting it may update after you choose a new location for a website.

There are keys under the "10.0" root ending in "Location" which can be changed in a similar fashion to affect the default directories for projects and other things.

As always, take care when modifying the Registry or you may break VS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is "ShellNew Extension for Visual Studio Solutions" you can use this , url http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/ShellNew-Extension-for-Visual-Studio-Solutions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On the new project window uncheck the box that says `Create directory for solution`.

or are you asking how to make it so that box is unchecked by default?